# How to get rid of Skype old receive notification?

Tags: skype, notifications

I'm using same Skype account @work and @home.
Problem is after I got home from work, "Home-Skype" receives all messages I exchanged with my contacts from someone's skype archive, and I all these (already read) messages appears as "new message notifications". It's really boring having to "acknowledge/read" them all once again.

That behavior started when updated lastest version of Skype.

How to disable that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete history. The thing you are talking about is synchronization of history.

Comment: yes, I am talking about synchronization of history, but I don't want to delete it, just to disable notifications when new piece of skype conversation history is received.